# How do prevent insert multiple record into sql server via pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

How do I prevent insert duplicated data and handler create table error. This is my code:

```
insert_query = '''INSERT INTO dbo.Tp_tabkeu(report_number,condition,power_error,status,Specification_dBM,CW_frequency) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) 
    WHERE report_number!=values(a), condition!=values(b), power_error!=values(c), status!=values(d), Specification_dBM!=values(e), CW_frequency!=values(f);'''

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        values = (row['report_num'], row['condition'], row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
```

Comment: Are you sure "WHERE" is a valid clause in an "INSERT" sql-statement?

Comment: It didnt valid,I have tried INSERT IGNORE, it didnt work too. do you have any idea?

Comment: @Jovisch - Are you using Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: yes,I use sql server.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... WHERE ...` is not valid syntax. However, you can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE ...`.

You've confirmed that you are using SQL Server, and `df.iterrows()` indicates that you are using pandas, therefore you really should also be using [SQLAlchemy](https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy/). (pandas relies on SQLAlchemy when working with databases other than SQLite.)

This example performs a conditional INSERT on a table named [team] ...

```
prov  city     team_name  
----  -------  -----------
ON    Toronto  Maple Leafs
```

... which has (prov, city) as its primary key.

```python
import sqlalchemy as sa

# ...

engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)

# ...

sql = sa.text("""\
INSERT INTO team (prov, city, team_name)
SELECT :prov AS prov, :city AS city, :team_name AS team_name
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM team WHERE prov = :prov AND city = :city)
""")
params = {'prov': 'AB', 'city': 'Calgary', 'team_name': 'Flames'}
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sql, params)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. is it insert value to sql server more faster compare to pyodbc if use sqlalchemy? besides, i have multiple report number with same value so is code above work also?